# Best way to iterate Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> in NVelocity

Tags: c#, nvelocity

I have a C# Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>, and I am trying to display the data with nVelocity template and also I am trying to get the keys of the dictionary with an index. I am newbie.

Please help me with how to access keys with an index e.g. I want to access key at 0 index and also how can I display data with iterations and how do we put "break" statements in foreach loops?

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="HeaderOne">
            <td align="left">Class</td>

            #foreach($services in $VolumeSummary)
                #foreach($item in $VolumeSummary[$services])
                    <td class="numeric-th">$item.AverageUnitPriceF</td>
                #end
                #break
            #end
            <td class="numeric-th">Average Price</td>
            <td class="numeric-th">Total</td>
        </tr>

        #foreach ($item in $TotalsByServiceAndTermYear)
        <tr style="color:#333;font-weight:normal;">
            <td>$item.Service</td>
            <td class="numeric-td">
                $!item.Year
            </td>
            <td class="numeric-td">
                $!item.AverageUnitPriceF
            </td>
            <td class="numeric-td">
                $!item.TotalPriceF
            </td>
        </tr>
        #end
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have no clue on NVelocity, but a `Dictionary` is not ordered and thus has no real index you can access to get the first key.

Comment: We can get all keys and then get first indexed key in C#

Comment: Sure, but this isn´t deterministic, in particular it may change in a newer .NET-version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVelocity just sits over the .NET objects so you can't get a item by index from a dictionary, but you can use `$dict.get_Item("key")` to get an item by key, which is the syntax for indexers as that is the underlying CLR method for the item indexer.

As others have mentioned a `Dictionary` has a non-deterministic sort order, consider using a `SortedDictionary`.

You can break from a `#foreach` using the `#break` directive, like your example. It was implemented in 2011 after we released v1.1.1, so you'll have to build from master or get a master build from our build server, otherwise you can workaround it by using a conditional to hide the contents.

```
#foreach($item in $dict)
  $item.Key
  #break
#end

#foreach($item in $dict)
  #if($velocityCount == 1)
    $item.Key
  #end
#end
```

Comment: #break isn't working... it gets displayed as it is... any reason?

Comment: @MuhammadZaib did you read my comment about the version number?

Comment: @MuhammadZaib glad that it worked, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers